# How to declare multiple variables with specifying type using As in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, declaration, variable-declaration

According to [this documentation by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement#declaring-multiple-variables), the following code can be used to make sure;

> a, b, and c are all Single; x and y are both Double

```vb
Dim a, b, c As Single, x, y As Double, i As Integer  
> a, b, and c are all Single; x and y are both Double
```

The logic behind this is as follows

> You can specify different data types for different variables by using a separate `As` clause for each variable you declare. Each variable takes the data type specified in the first `As` clause encountered after its variable name part.

However, when I checked with the debugger or `MsgBox VarType(a)`  output, this is not the case.

[image]

As you can see, it appears that `As` is only working for the variables right before itself, ie., `c`, `y` and `i`. All others are Variant/Empty and `VarType` returns 0.

Is this just the documentation being wrong, or am I missing something obvious?

Microsoft Visual Basic for Application 7.1.1056
Excel 2016 (Windows 10)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The documentation you've linked to isn't wrong, but it's written for VB.NET and not VBA.

In VBA, as you've observed, any variable declarations that aren't immediately followed by `As <type>` will be `Variant`.

Therefore you'd need to write:

```
Dim a As Single, b As Single, c As Single, x As Double, y As Double, i As Integer
```

Comment: Also see the correct documentation for VBA: [Dim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement)

Comment: Uh-huh, it clearly explains what I encountered. I did not realize there are many variations of Visual Basic language!

Comment: this is an insane language feature.

Comment: @NingNing Bug...

Comment: Have always wondered about this and thought I would finally do some checking and find out -- your answer made this v. easy and gave a clear, definitive answer, thanks!!  //  Also, thanks to @Pᴇʜ for the link to the Dim documentation.

Answer (score 7):

In VBA, when you declare

```
Dim a, b, c As Single
```

What it does is equivalent to this:

```
Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Single
```

I believe the best practice is to always declare variable in a separate row. It prevents this bug and also allows for faster scanning of the code. So the code would look like this:

```
Dim a As Single
Dim b As Single
Dim c As Single
```

Comment: Very well pointing this as a Bug instead of as a Feature

Comment: @Brethlosze This answer is not presenting this language feature as a bug. It is merely pointing out that other bugs can be prevented by adhering to a certain style.

Comment: @GSerg Your comment is merely denying, that we should understand the word "bug" in this answer, and replace it by the word "feature". This is not rational at all. I suggest you to focus on concrete ideas while writing comments on this site.

Comment: @Brethlosze My comment is pointing out that you have misrepresented the opinion expressed in this answer for future readers, which is a rather concrete idea. You are claiming that this answer is calling this style of declaration a bug. It isn't calling it a bug. Thus your comment is wrong and should be removed.

Comment: @GSerg The answer literally have the word *bug* in it. For further reference, please check why this site isn't for debating, or discussions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335903/how-can-we-handle-users-derailing-debates-in-comments) so you can have that into account for your future comments.

Comment: @Brethlosze Your misguided condescension is not appreciated. The words "this bug" used in the answer refer to the bug the programmer commits when they decide to declare the variables on a single line without understanding the implications, not to the intricacies of the language feature. Using your reasoning, [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059988/how-to-declare-multiple-variables-with-specifying-type-using-as-in-vba/55060249?noredirect=1#comment137817299_55060249) is a bug because it literally has the word *bug* in it.