# VBA code in Excel sometimes works but not always

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel VBA code which tries to edit a Word document by replacing certain strings with the cell values in my spreadsheet. Then it copies the entire word document in the clipboard (two pages of text so not too long).
The problem I have is that sometimes it would work perfectly, sometimes it would execute the code without errors but there would be nothing in the clipboard and sometimes it will come up with "Runtime error '4198': Command failed" and the error occurs in a random (non-consistent) stage of the "for each tagName" loop. Can you please help me understand what is wrong with it?

The code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document
Dim ref, savepath As String

'Options.PasteOptionKeepBulletsAndNumbers = True

ref = Cells(2, 4).Value

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wApp.Visible = False

Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="G:\Shared drives\Quotes\SWDSandFWDS\SWDS FWDS Quote Template.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
With wdoc
    For Each tagName In [tags]
        If tagName = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        
        Cells(tagName.Row, 5).Copy
    
        Do While .Application.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText:=tagName, Wrap:=wdFindContinue) = True
            If Cells(tagName.Row, 5) = "" Then
                .Application.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteHTML
                .Application.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Else
                .Application.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteRTF
                .Application.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            End If
        Loop
    Next tagName
    
    Set myRange = .Content
    With myRange.Find
            .Text = "[]"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True
    End With
    
    'Copy contents of quote to clipboard
    .Application.Selection.WholeStory
    .Application.Selection.Copy
    
    savepath = "G:\Shared drives\Quotes\SWDSandFWDS\TestOutput\"
    .SaveAs2 savepath & ref, _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    .Close
    '.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End With

'Close instances of Word
Dim objWord As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

' if no active Word is running >> exit Sub
If objWord Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

objWord.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing
'End Close instances of Word

MsgBox ("Quote coppied to clipboard.")

End Sub
```

I tried restarting everything and it seems to work the first time I run the code and sometimes the second time but then fails.

Comment: Probably not directly part of the problem but still a potential problem are: (a) [always use](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) `Option Explicit`, (b) [fully qualify your references](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references) when referring to any range (e.g. your use of `Cells`), and (c) be careful when [declaring multiple variables on a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060194/4717755).

Comment: When you use the clipboard area, sometime it fails. So, you need to use "on error resume next" in your code. You can do like this: <br/>
    On Error Resume Next 'Ignore the event error <br/>
    Cells(tagName.Row, 5).Copy<br/>
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then<br/>
        Err.Clear<br/>
        Cells(tagName.Row, 5).Copy<br/>
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then<br/>
            MsgBox Err.Description<br/>
            Stop 'Correct here<br/>
        End If<br/>
    End If<br/>
    On Error GoTo 0 'Back to normal<br/>

Comment: Looks like you should install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and pay attention to the code inspections.  You will learn a lot about how to write more correct VBA.