# VBA | type mismatch error at Split function (Solution is to separate the declaration)

Tags: excel, vba, split

Good day to all,

In a cell, user can enter the names of the Traders. They can enter 1 or many names, and names are to be separated by comma.

```
E.g. 1 (If only 1 Trader) 
Tom

E.g. 2 (If >1 Trader, use comma to separate) 
Tom, Justin Lee, Peter
```

My program will read the cell value to get the Trader names.
I first check if comma exist in the String, if so, I use split.

```
Dim AD_Trader, AD_Trader_Arr() As String

If InStr(AD_Trader, ",") <> 0 Then
            AD_Trader_Arr = Split(AD_Trader, ",")
            For TextX = LBound(AD_Trader_Arr()) To UBound(AD_Trader_Arr())
                MsgBox "TEST ADTrader = " & TextX & ")" & AD_Trader_Arr(TextX)
            Next TextX
End If
```

My program gave me a "Type mismatch" error at the Split function.

I have search on this forum and many mention I should declare the array as Variant.

Now here is the bizzare thing. If I declare the 2 variables in a separate line, there is no error

```
Dim AD_Trader As String
Dim AD_Trader_Arr() As String
```

I don't understand why. It is not the most elegant solution since I have many Arrays and their declaration is individual lines which lengthen my code.

Comment: It's probably getting confused about what type you want `AD_Trader` to be - in your first example that gives the error, what do `VarType(AD_Trader)` and `VarType(AD_Trader_Arr)` give? They should be 8 (vbString) and 8200 (8192 (vbArray) + 8) if you have the types you expected.

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding in vba that:
`Dim AD_Trader, AD_Trader_Arr() As String`
both variables are now declared as String. 
You have to declare every variable explicit, even if it is in one line. 
In your example AD_Trader is variant and not string

Comment: While your declaration is indeed [not what you think it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060194/11683), it cannot cause the type mismatch error. `Split` will work with either a string or a variant, and your array ends up declared correctly either way. The only way you could be having a type mismatch is if you have an error value in `AD_Trader`, but then you'd have an error upon trying to save it in `AD_Trader As String`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. AD_Trader is String, AD_Trader_Arr() is String Array. When I use Dedug and mouse over AD_Trader, I get "Tom, Justin Lee, Peter". Why can't Split() store each name into AD_Trader_Arr()?

Comment: It can and it does. Same with `Dim AD_Trader, AD_Trader_Arr() As String`.