How do I pull a date from a cell and see if it is in a range of dates
I have an Excel sheet of acts accomplished withe the dates and quantities. I am trying to iterate through each action and see if the date is within a range to combine all the similar act's quantities in a range of dates.
Whenever I pull from a cell it does not work. If I set the date value in the code itself, it works. The issue seems to be getting an actual date value from the cell.
sub test()  
    Dim top, bottom, middle As Date 
    top = "4/24/2024"    
    bottom = "05/25/2023"  
    middle = CDate(Cells(19, 7).value)  
    If middle >= bottom And middle <= top Then  
        MsgBox "yes;"  
    End If    
End Sub


"4/24/2024" and "05/25/2023" are strings, the date in your cell is likely a proper date (i.e. a number) you need to convert the strings to actual dates. This may be of use

Side note: you need to Dim each variable individually ex.: Dim top as String, bottom as String, middle As Date

More info based on @cybernetic.nomad comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060194/4717755
